# I need to convert a PDF into PDF/A using some opensource java library or program. Is it possible to achieve this?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfa

I need to convert a PDF into PDF/A using some java library or program. Is it possible to achieve this using some opensource library like itextPDF.
Could the same logic work in a generic format to convert pdf in pdf/A

Comment: This appears to be more suited for [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1):

try free Spire.PDF for java,
add the dependencies and use its converter. It seems to be an easy usage - I never done it myself - cause I didn't need it :) -

Here you can add the dependencies from the official website, https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Licensing/How-to-install-Spire.PDF-for-Java-from-Maven-Repository.html

and here you have a small sample of it, https://dev.to/jazzzzz/convert-pdf-to-pdf-a-with-a-free-java-api-4nm7

hope it could help.